# concat only if column value does not contain any specific prefix

Tags: sql, sql-like, concatenation

I want to add the prefix to column's data those who not like if the column's value is `123,OI:909, 456,OI:789`
then it updates to `OI:123,OI:909, OI:456, OI:789`

I tried following SQL

```
select col_1(case when col_1 NOT LIKE '%OI:%' then concat("OI:",col_1) end) from table_1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this syntax:

```
    select 
      case when col_1 NOT LIKE '%OI:%' 
        then concat("OI:",col_1) 
        ELSE col_1
      end   col1
      from table_1;
```

Comment: The correct spelling is "syntax" - there is no "i" is any English variant that I know of. Could you make a point of using the correct version in future?

Comment: @halfer   ... thanks ..  i hope   (syntax)   but in my mother language the y is rarely used ..  anyway thanks  again

Comment: Could I ask you to install an English spell checker? That would help reduce the workload on volunteer editors.